# Mocking Save Method using JUnit/Mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I'm writing a spring boot web app and am trying to figure out how to unit test a method that is simply saving a record to a db using junit and mockito, which I've never used before. Here is my save method:

```
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> saveRecord(@RequestBody Record record, BindingResult result) {
        if(!result.hasErrors()) {
            Record newRecord = recordsService.save(record);
            // Return the location of the created resource
            URI uri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{recordId}").buildAndExpand(newRecord.getId()).toUri();
            return new ResponseEntity<>(uri, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(result.getAllErrors(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
```

Notice that it returns a ResponseEntity<?> object, which I'm sort of unsure how to recreate over in the test since the ResponseEntity could include either the URI or the errors from the input, as well as the HttpStatus. So I was wondering if I could please get some assistance in writing this unit test. Let's say I've begun with this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class RecordsControllerTest {

    @Mock
    private RecordRepo recordRepo;

    @InjectMocks
    private RecordsService recordsService = new RecordsService();

     @Test
     public void saveRecordTest() {
         Record mock = new Record();

         //case 1: HttpStatus.CREATED
         Mockito.when(recordsService.save(Mockito.any(Record.class))).thenReturn(...);

         //case 2: HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST
         Mockito.when(recordsService.save(Mockito.any(Record.class))).thenReturn(...);

     }
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: I would recommend a different approach alltogether: instead of having a `hasError()`-method on the DTO, [bean validation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-bean-validation) can be used. Then, when bean validation fails, an [exception mapper](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring) can be used to map the `Exception` to a propper HTTP response.

Answer (score 2):

First: if you use @InjectMocks then you should not create the object `recordsService` on its own but let Mockito create it:

```
@InjectMocks
private RecordsService recordsService;
```

That said I recommend to use @WebMvcTest for testing Spring controllers.

```java
@WebMvcTest(GreetingController.class)
public class RecordsControllerTest {
    
     @Autowired
     private MockMvc mockMvc;

     @MockBean
     private RecordsService recordsService;

     @Test
     public void saveRecordTest() {
         Record mock = new Record();

         //case 1: HttpStatus.CREATED
         Mockito.when(recordsService.save(Mockito.any(Record.class))).thenReturn(...);

         //case 2: HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST
         Mockito.when(recordsService.save(Mockito.any(Record.class))).thenReturn(...);

     }
.
.
.
}
```

For more details see https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/